# How to pipe only recent git changes to flake8

Tags: linux, flake8

I would like to pipe only recent git changes to `flake8` (technically, `flake8_nb`) on the command line, including a number of flags, passing through `grep` to get only files that match a certain pattern. I

What I have tried is this:

```
git diff --name-only | grep "ipynb$" | flake8_nb --config=.flake8_nb_lite
```

However, this runs flake8 on all the files in the directory instead of just the ones that are the output of grep and ones that don't have recent changes. The problem is definitely the last step, as everything up to the final pipe is correct.

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for `xargs`

```
git diff --name-only -- '*.ipynb' | xargs flake8_nb --config=.flake8_nb_lite
```

I also made one other simplification: remove the `grep` since you can use `git`'s file matching directly

`xargs` will take arguments as input and turn them into positional arguments

if your arguments may contain spaces you might want to use `-z` (`git diff` option) and `-0` (`xargs` option) to break on null byte characters instead